# Implementing GCM on pre-4.0.4 devices

Tags: android

My app's minimum SDK is API 9 and I'm trying to implement GCM for it.  I'm using the following code based on what I read in the docs, is this the right approach?  This returns false sometimes on devices that are running 4.0.4 or higher that have Google Play Services installed.  It usually returns an error code of `ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED` in those cases.  Any ideas?

```
private boolean checkGcmStatus()
{
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode))
        {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("GCM", "Device can not register for GCM.");
        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the Android version, but the version of Google Play Services. What version of Google Play Services do those devices have?

Comment: Looks like one of them has 3.1.59, running Android 4.1.2.

I think I found the issue, I'm specifying `com.google.android.gms.version` metadata in my Manifest file.  Should I just remove this?

Comment: Removing the metadata element will make your app immediately crash as it is required by Google Play Services. 3.1.59 is a very old version of Google Play Services given that 4.2 is rolling out to all Android 2.3+ devices right now.

Comment: I want my app to work on all devices, even those that don't have google accounts set up.  So since those devices aren't getting these updates, what are my options?